Counting positive integer solutions to $a(b^2-c^2)=2024$

How many solutions does $a(b^2-c^2)=2024$ have such that $a,b,c$ are positive integers?

What I tried: The $(b^2-c^2)$ enticing to factorise, so I got
$$a(b-c)(b+c)=2024$$
Then I tried looking at all the triple factors of $2024$, but there are too many, so this is probably not the right method.
I need some help.

$2024=2^3\cdot 11\cdot 23$, so there are not too many decompositions into three factors. Say, $b-c=11$, $b+c=23$ gives $b=17$, $c=6$, $a=8$. And so on.

Yes but I feel there are still too many. b+c=23,232,234,238,11,112..., similarly with a

See art of problem solving, how to reduce the possibilities. See also $a(b^2-c^2)=1729$.

Choosing $b$ and $c$ determine $a$ uniquely so it suffices to find all positive $b$ and $c$ such that $(b-c)(b+c)$ divides $2024$. But this is equivalent to finding all positive $x<y$ such that $x$ and $y$ have the same parity, and $xy$ divides $2024$ (by letting $x=b-c$ and $y=b+c$).
Now as mentioned by Dietrich Burde in the comments, $2024=2^3\cdot 11\cdot 23$. So the possibilities are:

when $x$ and $y$ are both odd: $(x,y)=(1,11),(1,23),(1,11\cdot 23),(11,23)$.
when $x$ and $y$ are even, we can let $(x,y)=(2x',2y')$ where $x'<y'$ are positive integers such that $x'y'$ divides $2\cdot 11\cdot 23$. The possibilities are
$$
\begin{align*}
(x',y')=&(1,2),(1,11),(1,23),(1,2\cdot 11),(1,2\cdot 23),(1,11\cdot23),(1,2\cdot 11\cdot 23),\\
&(2,11),(2,23),(2,11\cdot 23),(11,23),(11,2\cdot 23),(2\cdot 11,23).
\end{align*}$$


Did you mean $23$ rather than $13$ in the last three possibilities?

Yup, sorry, fixed
